# Inventory database with calculated incremental values from movements by date

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I am tring to recreate an inventory database in which, by COD_ART, there is the stock value by date.

I have the data shown in picture [A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdAzR.jpg). The "inventory column" rapresent today inventory value while the "Movement" column rapresent the increased/deacreased value by date.

I would like to have a new column with the incremental quantity:

14/10/2021 | 925

13/10/2021 | 933

30/09/2021 | 733

etc.

Can anyone help me?
Thank you in advance for any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is called "Running Total" and its better to create a Measure than to create a Column, because technically speaking if you have multiple rows for same date, then running total in a column gets tricky. Also learning measures will be a really good skill under your belt.

And PowerBI has simplified creating this measure by adding the [Quick Measure](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/quick-measures-preview/#:%7E:text=date%20tables%20too.-,Running%20total,-This%20category%20) feature.

You can check out [this video starting at 6:41](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SFISgDUwuoA&t=6m41s) to get an understanding of how this works.

Steps:

1. Right-Click on stock-value column and select "New Quick measure"
2. In Calculation drop-down, select "Running Total"
3. If you right-clicked on the stock-value column, PowerBI will automatically add that column to "Base Value" field
4. Drag the date field into the "Field" section
5. Choose Ascending - which is selected by default.
6. Click Ok

Now the measure will be added to your table and you can create a table using this measure.

Comment: Hi Gangula, thank you very much for your advice but it does not completly solve my problem because I have multiple articles inside my database. 
I am very close to the solution with a custom column (code below) but I run out of memory and it stops whit an error. 
Any suggestion to do it in power query or make it more efficient? 
------ 
Stock = 
var x = 'MAG'[COD_ART]

return
CALCULATE(
    SUM(MAG[MOV]),
    'MAG'[DATE] >= EARLIER(MAG[DATE]) && MAG[COD_ART] == x)

Comment: Even if you have multiple articles, or multiple tables, it should work fine if the relationships are built correctly.

Comment: I'm afraid, I'm not sure how to improve your DAX code